# Get file download completed response from client browser using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, download

I want to get response after completion of each (successfull/failure) file download from the client browser. I'm using AngularJS for my frontend. I'm so much confused. So any one tell me, what I should do ?

Comment: Which is the back end you are using?

Comment: Thanks for response... i'm using Node js

Comment: can you please share your back end and front end code also?

Comment: In backend, i create Zip file on server side, then user downloaded successfully that file will deleted by the successful completion response.  So i need this response. So please tell me any possible code in angular to monitor the client browser.

Comment: You can try using the function I posted below.. Right?

Comment: Can you please let me know if it works or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89653/discussion-between-aravinth-and-sumodh-krishna).

Answer (score 0):

```
function download(url, callback, encoding){
        var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
            if (encoding){
                response.setEncoding(encoding);
            }
            var len = parseInt(response.headers['content-length'], 10);
            var body = "";
            var cur = 0;
            var obj = document.getElementById('js-progress');
            var total = len / 1048576; //1048576 - bytes in  1Megabyte

            response.on("data", function(chunk) {
                body += chunk;
                cur += chunk.length;
                obj.innerHTML = "Downloading " + (100.0 * cur / len).toFixed(2) + "% " + (cur / 1048576).toFixed(2) + " mb\r" + ".<br/> Total size: " + total.toFixed(2) + " mb";
            });

            response.on("end", function() {
                callback(body);
                obj.innerHTML = "Downloading complete";
            });

            request.on("error", function(e){
                console.log("Error: " + e.message);
            });

        });
    };
```

Try using this function since I don't know what have you done till now. Alternatively you can also try using the progress element of HTML5. 
[Support for Progress in browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=progress)